# Crear registro en laravel con modal y Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, ajax

Estoy intentando crear un `modal` que registre a una persona con su número de celular, lo quiero hacer con Ajax para que no me recargue la página ya que mas adelante habrá un `select` que se alimentará en simultáneo con la info de la base de datos.

Esto es lo que tengo:

Ruta

```
Route::post('turnos/addDeliveryModal', [App\Http\Controllers\TurnoController::class, 'addDeliveryModal'])->name('turnos.addDeliveryModal');
```

Controlador

```
public function addDeliveryModal(Request $request){
    $delivery = New Delivery();

    $delivery->nombDelivery = $request->nombDelivery;
    $delivery->celDelivery = $request->celDelivery;

    $delivery->save();

    return response()->json($delivery);
}
```

Formulario modal

```
<form method="POST" id="addDeliveryModal">
                    @csrf                
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-control-label">Nombre del Delivery</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nombDelivery" class="form-control form-control-alternative" required>                    
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-control-label">Telefono o Celular</label>
                            <input type="text" name="celDelivery" class="form-control form-control-alternative" required>                    
                        </div>
                    </div>            
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger  ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    </div>  
                </form>
```

Ajax

```
$("#addDeliveryModal").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        let nombDelivery = $("#nombDelivery").val();
        let celDelivery = $("#celDelivery").val();
        let _token = $("input[name=_token]").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('turnos.addDeliveryModal')}}",
            type: "POST",
            data:{
                nombDelivery:nombDelivery,
                celDelivery:celDelivery,
                _token:_token
            },
            success:function(response)
            {
                if(response){
                    console.log("hola");
                }else{
                    console.log("hola2");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Screenshot del Formulario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Screenshot del error que me bota

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error claramente me dice que no esta registrada con el metodo POST, cuando si lo esta, ya recargue las rutas y el problema persiste
Espero puedan hecharme una mano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy probable que aunque en tu archivo de rutas lo tienes definido de esta manera:

```
Route::post('turnos/addDeliveryModal', [App\Http\Controllers\TurnoController::class, 'addDeliveryModal'])->name('turnos.addDeliveryModal');
```

Laravel espere una estructura diferente.

Una forma de validar como está esperando la ruta de lado de Laravel es utilizando el comando:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Aquí puedes revisar algunos ejemplos de uso.
[Uso de route list command](https://stillat.com/blog/2016/12/07/laravel-artisan-route-command-the-routelist-command#:%7E:text=The%20route%3Alist%20command%20can,includes%20in%20the%20generated%20table.)

También podrías cambiar la forma de construir tu ruta post en el archivo de rutas:

```
Route::get('turnos/addDeliveryModal', 'TurnoController@addDeliveryModal')->name('turnos.addDeliveryModal');
```

Aquí la doc de Laravel especifica el uso de rutas.
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing)

Answer (score 3):

tengo varios puntos que te marcaría (siempre para aprender).

Si tu página se está actualizando es probable que el `submit` se esté realizando sobre un `action` inexistente. Es decir, se está enviando un post a la misma url. Te recomiendo que pruebes agregando:

```
<form action="#" ...>
```

Si eso funciona significa que tu código de javascript que intercepta el formulario, está retornando un valor `true`. Podés cancelar al final de tu función javascript haciendo esto:

```
return false;
```

**Algunas recomendaciones:**

En laravel existen métodos que facilitan la creación de los objetos. Te recomiendo que leas [esta documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method). Podés generar tu función de un modo mucho más legible.

```
public function addDeliveryModal(Request $request)
{
    $delivery = Delivery::create([
        'nombDelivery' => $request->nombDelivery;
        'celDelivery' => $request->celDelivery;
    ]);

    return response()->json($delivery);
}
```

Te recomiendo que a tus funciones de creación con datos que ingresa el usuario sean siempre [validadas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic). Debés controlar y mostrar los errores si el usuario intenta escribir una cadena de texto de 5000 caracteres en un campo que permite 100 (por ejemplo).

```
public function addDeliveryModal(Request $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'nombDelivery' => 'required|max:255',
        'celDelivery' => 'required|numeric',
    ]);
    // ...
}
```

Si entrás en el modo de desarrollador de tu browser, y elegís la pestaña "network" podrás tener más información acerca de tus llamadas vía ajax. Quizás ahí encuentres muchos de tus errores (esto era lo que te iba a pedir pero dada la foto veo que el formulario se está enviando normal más allá del ajax).

[image: Imagen de la pestaña network]

Comment: Tenias muchas razon querido amigo!
Muchas Gracias por tu apoyo